# isn't it possible to get partial derivatives for x^(1/3)y^(1/3)?

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I'm studying "vector calculus written by Jerrold E.marsden, Anthony Tromba 6th Ed"

My problem is I couldn't understand example 4 in 2.3section

They said that they can get partial derivatives of $x^{1/3}y^{1/3}$ at (0,0) like below
$$f_x(x,y)=lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{0-0}{h}=0$$

Next paragraph, they said there are no partial derivatives in $x^{1/3}y^{1/3}$ because It doesn't have tangent plane at (0,0)

I'm confusing these two contradictory explanation.

It seems like that I could get partial derivatives by definition of partial derivative.

But I know It couldn't be happen

what is the turth of this example?

Comment: Assuming that $f(0,0)$ is defined as $0$, partial derivatives do exist. The second statement is not correct.

Comment: But If you are right, this function has partial derivatives and be a continous. This conditions make it differentiable by theorem. However this example isn't differentiable. So how can I understand this contradiction?

Comment: The partial derivatives do not even have a limit at the orgin. For differentiabilty you want the partial derivatves to be continuous.

Comment: So did you mean that for differentiability, partial derivatives to be continous not the original function?

Comment: Exactly. Continuity of the original function is not enough.

Comment: Does it really say "there are no partial derivatives" or does it say that the function is not differentiable? Those are not the same thing.

Comment: No, My first question is " Does partial derivatives exist?" but I can find the my misunderstood about theorem of differentiation in process of Q&A. The core is partial derivatives not differentiable.